# Singleton-like pattern for a project

Tags: c#, singleton

I'm changing the inner implementation of a project.  In order to do so, I've created an interface that will be implemented in 2 different ways.

One of this ways is by class `A`, which is a wrapper for an outside class (class "`B`") from a .dll file (a product of other team).

Class `B` is a private a member of class `A`.  Class `B` ctor takes an argument, which does not change during the run of my application. It needed to be created only once, and to stay available for class `A` everywhere in the code.

Class `A` is an implementation of interface.  It use the capabilities of class `B` in order to implement it's functions, and obviously needed to be available also everywhere in the code.

I've concluded that:

Class `A` has to be:

1. explicitly created once (hence, not static)
2. only once, (because I need `B` to be created only once.)
3. accessible from anywhere in the code
4. have a member (`B`) that must initialized once, and only once (private member, needed only inside class `A`)

Concerning condition #4, ideally I would like to initialize `B` in the constructor.

A bit similar to singleton pattern, with the exception of wanting to initialize a member in the constructor.

I've come to a solution, and would like to get feedback.

```
public sealed class A
{
   private static SomeClass B = null; // the "must initialized only once" member
   // setting B:
   private void setB(int i)
   {
      B = new SomeClass(i);
   }
   // ctor
   public A(int i)
   {
      if(B == null)
         setB(i);
      else throw new Exception("An instance of A can be created only once");
   }     
}
```

The idea is to assign the class to static object at the beginning of the code.  It's not very neat, but it compiles and seems to do the job just right.  I don't use singleton since it won't be possible to initialize the member in the ctor.  By the way, thread safety is not a concern here.

`SomeClass` needed only inside class `A`. `SomeClass` comes from dll, and class `A` kind of wrapping it.  `A` does answering cross-cutting concern, it is an implementation of Interface used all over the code. I've tried to implement singleton, but as much as I tried it didn't answer my needs.

Comment: How are you going to access your SomeClass object from outside of class A?

Comment: Why not go with a real, full-blown *Singleton* implementation? Thread safety not being an issue *now* might become an issue *later*... Why does it need to be *accessible from anywhere in the code*? Is it addressing a cross-cutting concern? Have you considered any alternative approaches?

Comment: You've passed off the Singleton handling responsibility to `A`, which is not a Singleton, and then thrown an exception when calling code creates an instance of A because it's actually a roundabout Singleton.

Comment: Is the project only starting, or it's well under way?

Comment: true, but I can't change SomeClass, and making A singleton will make it difficult to initialize B in the ctor.

Comment: It's an big project I've to maintain, and now I'm changing some major inner implementation.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! If possible, please add some more context to your question. The more you tell us about what your **real** code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to give you better help. **Why** do you need a singleton in your code? What is it's real purpose?

Comment: Simon is right, this is pretty much impossible to review as is. You would get much better (and more applicable) answers with real code and more context ;)

Comment: My way of handling this would be to simply never create an instance of the class directly, and let the same instance be injected to everything that needs it (through a MEF import in my case). It won't stop other programmers from misusing your code by newing up more instances, but that isn't really your problem.

Comment: You have the beginnings of a good question, but [hypothetical code lacks sufficient detail to be reviewed](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/9357). We have therefore closed this question as off-topic, but would love to see you ask another question with real identifiers and a real use case so that we can give it a proper review.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to wrap `SomeClass`, make your wrapper an *abstraction*:

```
public interface ISomeClassWrapper
{
    // expose the methods and properties you want to wrap
}
```

Then everywhere it's needed in the code, replace static method calls like this:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    SomeClass.Xyz();
}
```

With something like this:

```
public class MyOtherClass
{
    private readonly ISomeClassWrapper _wrapper;

    public MyOtherClass(ISomeClassWrapper wrapper)
    {
        _wrapper = wrapper;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _wrapper.Xyz();
    }
}
```

Now, if you're worried about how many instances of `SomeClassWrapper` (which implements `ISomeClassWrapper` but `MyOtherClass` doesn't need to know that), **don't instantiate it. ever.**

How do you ensure there's only 1 instance of it?

When you've replaced `SomeClass.Xyz();` with `_wrapper.Xyz();`, you've done several things:

- `MyOtherClass` is now *decoupled* from `SomeClass`, and even from `SomeClassWrapper`.
- The `ISomeClassWrapper` dependency is now *statically declared as such*, so just by looking at `MyOtherClass`'s constructor you *know* it needs an implementation for `ISomeClassWrapper` to carry out its tasks.
- You can now provide a fake/mock implementation of `ISomeClassWrapper`, and write a test for `DoSomething()` without worrying about side-effects in code that you have no control over.
- The code that's responsible for providing the `ISomeClassWrapper` instance/implementation, is also responsible for passing *everyone that wants an `ISomeClassWrapper` instance*, the same instance. Most IoC containers can do this very, very easily.

Comment: look promising, i'll try it and report back

Comment: Good! If you're going to use an IoC container, make sure *no code depends in it*, otherwise you'll fall into the Service Locator trap; also if you're taking the Dependency Injection route, make sure you go *all the way* about it; I'd recommend Mark Seemann's *Dependency Injection in .net*, an excellent read on the subject ;)

Comment: What class implements `ISomeClassWrapper`? You still need to create an instance of whatever it is to pass to `MyOtherClass`, which in and of itself means you can create more than one instance of it anyway.

Comment: The hardest part about avoiding a service locator is how similar it looks to proper dependency injection in some cases. The primary reason I've started using MEF is that it offers an attributed model, which allows you to avoid resolving your dependencies in code altogether; the attributed properties and constructors are simply fulfilled as available. @Brandon: While more than one instance *can* be created, if injected, it won't be. If someone does make another instance in your project, punch them.

Comment: @Brandon the wrapper itself! And yes, nothing *prevents* `new`ing up another instance somewhere else, except following the DI pattern and sticking to it (hence "going all the way about it")

Comment: @Mat'sMug I don't want to cloud up this question so I'll stick to the chat after this: I assumed it was the wrapped class implementing, but I guess I was just hoping that it wasn't "Well, hopefully other developers don't do this", speaking of creating new instances. I like the idea of the DI pattern, but from past experience (and Magus' comment), I'd be doing more punching than developing.